# Facebook publish to groups after API 2.4

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

After Facebook launched their new API 2.4 in July, I have noticed that the possibility to publish to groups is restricted.

Are there now no way of publishing a message to a group on behalf of a user?

Comment: Would be nice if people give a short comment on why they down vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `user_managed_groups` permission and the `/group-id/feed` endpoint - which is explained very well in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/group/feed#publish

You can only post to groups you manage.

Comment: Just be aware that you can only post to groups that you are admin of

Comment: Okay, that is what I was afraid of. I would like to post to groups I'm not admin of. So I guess there are no way of posting to groups you are not admin of anymore.

Comment: exactly, they are off limits.